# D3js: Creating vertical grid lines at particular coordinates

Tags: d3.js

I need to create vertical grid lines as shown in the below image which intersect with the lowest value of each cycle.

[image]

Here's the plunker I have created: http://plnkr.co/edit/0vuETBsOOvEPBqIpUd53?p=preview

The grid lines are being rendered by a method called `renderGridLines()`.

Comment: Can you tell us what you've tried and what specifically you're struggling with?

Comment: you can have a look at the plunker mentioned in my question. What should I modify in renderGridLines() method to achieve the grid lines in the shown image

Comment: What you're trying to do will involve much more than altering your existing function. You need to create an algorithm to find all of the local minima within the range of your dataset, and then have a function that creates a line for each of the x-coordinates in that set of points. It's going to involve quite a bit of calculus. You might want to try asking in [**this group**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) for suggestions on how to approach your problem in the abstract, and then you can try to implement it in javascript. Good luck.

Comment: sorry wrong link, I meant the Math group, [**HERE**](http://math.stackexchange.com/)